# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@deck.gl/experimental-layers'

Tags: javascript, java, dictionary, npm, command

I am trying to run `npm start` on the trip example in `deck.gl`.
Other examples open fine with me but for trip I'm facing this error using npm:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@deck.gl/experimental-layers'
>   in '/Users/username/deck.gl/deck.gl/examples/website/trips'  @
>   ./app.js 6:0-56 79:10-20  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./app.js

The web browser launched, but nothing was displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the missing package:

`npm install --save @deck.gl/experimental-layers`